# Get source data from API

Tags: api, rest, informatica

My team is trying to configure an Informatica job that pulls data from the [SurveyCTO](https://www.surveycto.com/blog/6-tips-for-automating-survey-data-management-with-surveycto-api/) API.  According to the documentation, the output is in CSV or JSON format.

I've seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaKp9Tewbr0&t=79s) and it looks like it's using ODBC to configure a JSON driver.

Is there a more direct / native way to connect to the API in Informatica?  How can I setup the Informatica job to pull the data directly from the API?

**Update**
We were able to find the API Connector in our cloud PowerCenter and are trying to configure the Swagger file.  We successfully created a Swagger file for a public API, but were unable to do so for our SurveyCTO API.  We get an `invalid URL` error:

[image]

The SurveyCTO API URL is valid -- we tested it and it returned results, outside of Informatica.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

**References**
[Generating a Swagger file](https://docs.informatica.com/cloud-common-services/administrator/current-version/connections/swagger-file-generation-for-rest-v2-connections/generating-a-swagger-file.html)
[HOW TO: Generate Swagger file in IICS](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/527268?language=en_US)

Comment: Hi - have you tried using the Informatica REST connector? https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration-connectors/current-version/rest-v2-connector.html

Comment: The REST connector is an option but it can be a bit fiddly according to my experience. If you have CSV as an option and it can be automated I would go with that.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  This looks exactly like what we want, except it turns out we are using a version of PowerCenter which is not yet in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks, but we are trying to avoid CSV because some of our input is coming with special characters which we are trying to use for end-of-line and delimiters.  We are hoping to avoid these issues by using JSON.

Comment: Hi, not sure what your point is - does the version of the product that you are using not have REST API as a connector type and have you not found the relevant documentation for your product version?

Comment: We are on version 10.5.2 (on-premise).  Where can we check to see if we have the API connector type available?  If it's not available in this version, do you know what version it first became available in?  FYI, we are not licensed for the Web Consumer Connector.

Comment: We are trying to convert a workflow to use the API instead of intermediary CSV files.  Apologies for the newbie questions, this is our first attempt.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: 1) Read the documentation to see what's available 2) Check you license to so see what you are able to use 3) Talk to your Informatica Account Manager

Comment: Thanks, we were able to make some progress - please see edited post above.  Any suggestions on the `invalid URL` issue we're seeing with Informatica's Swagger File generator?  We can connect OK to the SurveyCTO API outside of here, so maybe we're not configuring it properly?  We tried different permutations of the API Path / Base Path fields.

Comment: If you read the documentation for creating a swagger file, for the URL it states “Mandatory. URL consists of the host name and port number. For example: http://localhost:8000”. That’s not what you have in the screenshot

Comment: I read the documentation.  The public API we configured did not require a port number.

Comment: The documentation says that the port number is required, so you probably need to find out what the default port number being used by the API is (probably 8000) and try that